# Implementing a CI with gitlab

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a **node.js** on gitlab repo and I am trying to push it into AWS EC2 Ubntu server using CI pipeline.

I am trying to implement a **CI pipeline** between my gitlab repo and the EC2 instance in a way that every time I push a new code the pipeline gets triggered and the code goes to EC2 server automatically.

I have added **environment** with **name** and the **url** to yaml file. (the url is the AWS server address with git installed on it)

My current **.gitlab-ci.yml** file looks like below:

```html
image: node:6.10.3

stages:
  - ver
  - init
  - tests
  - deploy

ver:
  stage: ver
  script:
    - node --version
    - whoami
init:
  stage: init
  script:
    - npm cache clean
    - rm -rf node-modules
    - npm install
run_tests:
  stage: tests
  before_script: 
    - chmod 0777 ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha
  script:
    - npm test

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Going to deploy to staging server"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://EC2DNS_Address.amazonaws.com/test/ci-test

  only:
    - master
```

when I commit a new changes I can see the pipeline gets triggers but I don't see any changes applied to the server.

How can I push these changes into my ubuntu server? **do I need something more than the environment tag?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You also need to implement the actual deploy by using script tags. I'm afraid there is no magical way this will happen.

So either use SCP or SSH commands or whatever you use to deploy your application to the server you specify in `environment`.

As the [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html) explain:

> Environments are like tags for your CI jobs, describing where code
>   gets deployed. Deployments are created when **jobs deploy** versions of
>   code to environments, so every environment can have one or more
>   deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Check status of **deploy** stage to find the problem.

to deploy on AWS set sensitive variables (name, access keys) in the Project Setting (in the Gitlab) and use them in your gitlab-ci.yml

I think this [link](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/08/26/ci-deployment-and-environments/) is for you.